# Format object from API call to dataTable format on Google Charts (ng2-google-charts)

Tags: angular, foreach, ng2-google-chart

I'm using [ng2-google-charts](https://www.devrandom.it/software/ng2-google-charts/index.html) to build a geoChart in an Angular 10 project.
Everything works good with fixed data, the problem I have is that I'm not sure how to format (and add) the data from an API call.

This is my geoChart property that works perfectly with fixed data

```
public geoChart: GoogleChartInterface = {
   chartType: 'GeoChart',    
   dataTable: [
     ['Country', 'Ice Machines'],
     ['Austria', 1],
     ['Belgium', 2],
     ['Bulgaria', 3],    
   ],
   options: {},
};
```

This is the object (data.response) that I receive from the API -->
[{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]

```
0: {paisCode: "DE", total: 1}
1: {paisCode: "DK", total: 1}
2: {paisCode: "ES", total: 1}
3: {paisCode: "FR", total: 1}
4: {paisCode: "NL", total: 1}
5: {paisCode: "RO", total: 1}
length: 6
```

This is what I'm trying:

```
data.response.forEach(element => {
   let countryCode = element.paisCode;
   let totalPerCountry = element.total;
   //formattedDataMap +=  "[" + "'" + countryCode +"'" + ',' + totalPerCountry + "],";
   this.geoChart.dataTable.push('[' + countryCode + ',' + totalPerCountry + ']')
   formattedDataMap.push('[' + countryCode + ',' + totalPerCountry + ']')
   //console.log(formattedDataMap);
})
```

But the data is not added **correctly**:

```
0: (2) ["Country", "Total"]
1: (2) ["Austria", 1]
2: (2) ["Belgium", 2]
3: (2) ["Bulgaria", 3]
4: "[DE,1]"
5: "[DK,1]"
6: "[ES,3]"
7: "[FR,1]"
8: "[NL,1]"
9: "[RO,1]"
```

**Update:**
I've updated my method, however nothing happens to the array. It's the same size and has the same elements.

```
  async myMethod() {
     if (this.account.email) {
        (await this.myService.MyMethod())
        .pipe(first())
        .subscribe(async (data: any) => {        
           this.geoChart.dataTable.concat(                
             data.response.reduce((acc, curr) => {
             acc.push([curr['paisCode'], curr['total']]);
             return acc;
           }, [])
        ); 
        console.log(this.geoChart.dataTable);
    });       
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using map worked:

```
   data.response.map(item => {
      this.geoChart.dataTable.push([item.paisCode, item.total]);
   })
```

Answer (score 0):

You're producing strings instead of arrays. You could try to use the `Array#reduce` method to modify the data from the API

```js
const input = [{paisCode: "DE", total: 1}, {paisCode: "DK", total: 1}, {paisCode: "ES", total: 1}, {paisCode: "FR", total: 1}, {paisCode: "NL", total: 1}, {paisCode: "RO", total: 1}];

const output = input.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  acc.push([curr['paisCode'], curr['total']]);
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(output);
```

In your case it'd look like the following

```js
this.someService.getData().subscribe({
  next: data => {
    this.geoChart.dataTable.concat(                     // <-- append new values to exisiting values
      data.response.reduce((acc, curr) => {
        acc.push([curr['paisCode'], curr['total']]);
        return acc;
      }, [])
    );
  },
  error: error => {
    // handle error
  }
});
```

You could also append new values to existing values using `Array#concat` method.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've updated my method and now the console.log(this.geoChart.dataTable); outputs the original array with no changes at all. Can you take a look?

Comment: I don't actually see a need to mix async await with observables here. Could you please show how the method in service is implemented?

Comment: Your code should work, but using map it worked. Thank you!